# Number of independent parity checks satisfied by a code

Tags: coding-theory

I have been studying quantum error correction codes and as background, I am currently studying the theory of classical linear codes. Despite many efforts, I am unable to understand the following excerpt:

**Any given parity check u divides Hamming space exactly in half,into those vectors which satisfy u and those that do not.Therefore,the 2^k vectors of a linear subspace in 2^n Hamming space can satisfy at most n−k linearly independent parity
checks.These parity checks together form the parity check matrix H, which is another way to define the
linear subspace.**

Comment: Have you taken linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

**Any given parity check $u$ divides Hamming space exactly in half, into those vectors which satisfy $u$ and those that do not.**

Suppose your Hamming space is $X = \{0,1\}^n$. A non-zero parity check $u$ divides $X$ into two sets: $X_0 = \{ x \in X \mid \langle x,u \rangle = 0 \}$ and $X_1 = \{ x \in X \mid \langle x,u \rangle = 1 \}$. The two sets have equal size $2^{n-1}$.

Indeed, let $v$ be some non-zero vector such that $\langle u,v \rangle = 1$ (for example, $v$ could contain a single 1 entry, at some index in which $u$ also has a 1 entry). If $x \in X_0$ then $x + v \in X_1$, and conversely, if $x \in X_1$ then $x + v \in X_0$. Hence we can partition $X$ into pairs $(x,x+v)$ in which the first member is in $X_0$ and the second in $X_1$.

Here are two illustrating examples. If $u = (1,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n-1\text{ copies}})$ then $X_0$ consists of all vectors with 0 in the first coordinate, and $X_1$ consists of all vectors with 1 in the first coordinate. If $u = (\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n \text{ copies}})$ then $X_0$ consists of all vectors with even parity, and $X_1$ consists of all vectors with odd parity.

**Therefore, the $2^k$ vectors of a linear subspace in $2^n$ Hamming space can satisfy at most $n−k$ linearly independent parity checks.** The statement here actually doesn't follow from the preceding statement. However, it is similar in spirit (and a generalization of the preceding statement). Earlier we have considered a single parity check $u$. We showed that if $u$ is non-zero, then the set $\{x \in X \mid \langle x,u \rangle = 0\}$ contains exactly half the space. If $u = 0$ then it consists of the entire space.

Now we are considering the common solutions of $m$ different vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_m$. The set $C = \{x \in X \mid \langle x,u_1 \rangle = \cdots = \langle x,u_m \rangle = 0\}$ contains at least $2^{n-m}$ vectors. If the vectors are linearly independent (this generalizes the condition $u \neq 0$), then $C$ contains exactly $2^{n-m}$ vectors. More generally, $C$ contains $2^{n-d}$ vectors, where $d$ is the dimension of the linear span of the vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_m$. I won't prove all these statements, but this is basic linear algebra.

If $C$ is a linear subspace containing $2^k$ vectors, and every element $x \in C$ satisfies $\langle x,u_1 \rangle = \cdots = \langle x,u_m \rangle = 0$, then the dimension of the span of $u_1,\ldots,u_m$ is at most $n-k$, per the discussion above. If we know that $u_1,\ldots,u_m$ are linearly independent, then the dimension of their span is $m$, and so $m \leq n-k$.

**These parity checks together form the parity check matrix $H$, which is another way to define the linear subspace.**

We can describe a linear code in two ways. One is using a generator matrix $G$: the linear code consists of all linear combinations of the rows. The other is using a parity check matrix $H$: the code consists of all vectors whose inner product with each row is 0. (Some books use rows, other columns.) Using our earlier notation, the rows of $H$ are just the vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_m$, where we insist that the vectors be linearly independent (the same holds for generator matrices).

Here is an example. Let $n = 3$, and consider the code whose generator matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(We note that the same code has many generator matrices, and many parity check matrices.)

The code consists of all linear combinations of the rows:
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$
You can check that these are exactly the vectors with even parity. Hence a parity check matrix for this code (in this degenerate case, the *unique* parity check matrix) is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We can also treat this as a generator matrix of a code. The resulting code is known as the *dual code* (dual to the code for which this matrix functions as a parity check matrix).